# Even or odd, periodic or not $k>0 \; ; \forall x\in\mathbb{R}, f(x+k)=f(k-x)\; and\; f(2k+x)=-f(2k-x) $

Tags: periodic-functions, even-and-odd-functions

I need to know if the function $f$ are odd or even, and I need to know if it periodic or not.
$$k>0 \; ; \forall x\in\mathbb{R}, f(x+k)=f(k-x)\; and\; f(2k+x)=-f(2k-x) $$
I've tried to substitute x with different values this what I got :
$$ x=0 \; ; f(2k)=-f(2k)$$
$$ x=k \; ; f(2k)=f(0)\; and\; f(3k)=-f(k) $$
$$f(3k)=f(2k+k)=f(k-2k)=f(-k)$$
Then,
$$f(-k)=-f(k) $$ it's not enough to say $f$ is odd  $(k>0)$ the function $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$.
Any help please.

Comment: *Hint*: Prove that $f$ has $4k$ as a period.